match to the closest pattern in regex
Hiii,
I have an example here:
(e1) - [:(Causal|Result|SubEvent)*0..1] -> ()

(e:Type1|Type2) - [:Next] -> (e2)

I want to extract (e1), () in first example and  (e:Type1|Type2), (e2) in example 2.
there are just some alpha character and : and | inside the round brackets, no spaces in side the round brackets.
I have tried: (\(.*\)) but its gonna get until the final close bracket.

I  mean I might change .* to the possible character like \w or something but I really want to know what the way to catch the closest pattern Thank youuuuu.

It has always been .*?. Mind . does not always match linebreaks, replace with [\w\W]*? or use the s flag (m in Onigmo) then.

@WiktorStribiżew hi thank you, but it gonna get (Causal|Result|SubEvent) which I don't want hmmm maybe i'm so greedy

Try ^\([^()]*\)|\([^()]*\)$

@jupyter Please provide the exact requirements. Without it's more or less guessing. I'd also go with @HaoWu's comment for matching the content, negation is usually more efficient than lazy dot. Possible guesses 1.) HaoWu's comment: Only at start/end... furthermore I could ask myself 2:) Or also match those, that are followed by a space: \([^)(]*\)(?!\S) 3.) Or only if not inside any square brackets: \([^)(]*\)(?![^\]\[]*\]) - Finally: What regex-environment? I'll look into his profile! (bad idea)

Hi, Thank you @HaoWu. but can we do it without the constraint $ that the close bracket must be the end of the string?  @bobble hi, sorry it's python environment and there is no space inside the round brackets as well as square brackets.

Not a problem, just remove all inside [...], withre.sub(r'\[[^][]*]', '', text) and then use \(.*?\) / \([^()]*\)
